# Iron Router for Meteor On Windows

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

Whenever I try to install Iron:Router on Windows it does not seem to work, and it tells me that there is no such package ! Also is there any way I can get meteorite to work on windows ?

Comment: Have you tried `meteor add iron:router` ? What does it outputs ?

Comment: It out puts no such package, and I have the latest Meteor version and my computer is running on windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Run `meteor add iron:router`.

Meteorite is for old versions of Meteor.

Comment: I did it outputs no suck package

Answer (score 0):

Meteorite is deprecated. Adding packages is built into meteor by default now. Use https://atmospherejs.com/ as it is the preferred and easiest way to utilize packages in meteor. To add a package open your command line and type:

`meteor add author:title`

Adding iron router would look like:

`meteor add iron:router`

The author is `iron` and the package title is `router`

Comment: It out puts no such package

Comment: Weird... Reinstall meteor and restart your machine. Are you using `meteor add iron:router` within a project?

Comment: Yes I am,  and I deleted and reinstalled meteor but I am still facing the same problem